# Creating branch inside a branch in git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

In my repository, I have a master branch and then a staging branch coming out of master branch. Now I need to add a third branch that should come out from staging branch. That means I need a branch coming out of another branch. Can anyone help in this?

The syntax I used for creating branch is like this:

```
git branch <name_of_your_new_branch>

git push origin <name_of_your_new_branch>

git checkout <name_of_your_new_branch>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can create your branch locally:

```
git checkout staging
git checkout -b newBranch
```

or, one line:

```
git checkout -b newBranch staging
```

That will start from the current HEAD of `staging`, but note that a branch doesn't really comes from another branch: it comes from a commit (and that commit can be part of multiple branches).

You can then push your new branch, [tracking the the remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309) in one command:

```
git push -u origin newBranch
```